# PHP ifelse error with partial files

Tags: php

Here is the issue there are 3 files
1. head.php
2. nav.php
3. footer.php

Problem is if user `logged in` then i want to show the different layout structure if not then another structure. What I'm doing is i don't want to repeat views like html opening or closing tag in every file so that's why I'm creating partial files for that like `head.php` and so on. So it's a problem in control structure statement `if else` clause, It is written on `head.php` file and there are errors come.
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in head.php`
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF), expecting end of file footer.php`

I know PHP says write `if else` clause on the same file and end it. But is there a way to solve this problem.

Code head.php:

```
<?php $loggedIn = false; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale =1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php if (!$loggedIn) : ?>
    <p>You are not logged in </p>
    <?php require 'footer.php'; ?>
<?php else :
require 'nav.php';
require 'footer.php.php'; ?>
```

Code nav.php:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Logged Out</a></li>
    </ul>

</nav>
```

Code footer.php:

```
</body>
</html>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You __can't__ split `if` between several files. Over.

Comment: You can add same condition in files you needed

Comment: @u_mulder then what approach i use

Comment: @u_mulder you mark this question with the duplicate question that doesn't make sense i'm just asking about approach what you use for that kind of problem

Comment: This question is a duplicate of that one - because you get the same error. That being said, you can't split conditions up into different files like that. You need to check for that condition for each file (in which case you need to ensure the variable you are testing on is within the scope), or restructure your approach. Those are your two options.

Comment: @JohnDoe You can use switch statement to achieve this. Enter this code in your head.php file. `<body>
<?php switch ($loggedIn): ?>
<?php case 0: ?>
        <p>You are not logged in </p>
        <?php require 'footer.php';
        break;
        ?>

    <?php case 1:
        require 'nav.php';
        require 'footer.php';
        break;
        ?>
    <?php endswitch; ?>`